# Energy stored in the capacitor increase when the capacitance decrease

Tags: voltage, capacitor, capacitance, energy, charge

Help!!!!Energy stored in the capacitor increase when the capacitance decrease.Suggest an explanation for this energy increase, making reference to conservation of energy.

Question [paper 3,Q4(D)(ii)] http://content.yudu.com/Library/A223vp/FreeMicrosoftPoints/resources/32.htm

Comment: Q=C*V, charge is conserved in this case.  Work must have been done to decrease the capacitance... ie pulling the plates apart.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a parallel plate capacitor with some charge on it one plate will be positively charged and the other negative.  To decrease the capacitance, you pull the plates apart.  Because the plates are oppositely charged, they attract, and you have to do work to separate them.  This increases the energy stored.